# Can I do more than ctrl z/ go back very far into my model?

Tags: workflow

I really messed up with subdivisions and this is probably the fifth time restarting my model. I am very new to blender. I tried ctrl z but that could only go back a few times. Is there a way to either go back several times with undo or reload an older version of that file?
If it matters, my issue is that at first I had too many subdivisions, so I used ctrl e to unsubdivide, but it changed my squares to triangles and other shapes that are not sqaures.
[image: If you know a way to manually fix this, please tell too]

Comment: If there is a way to manually fix this error, please tell too.

Comment: You can increase the number of available undo steps in *User Preferences > Editing > Steps*, but this obviously wont work after the fact. Only other option is checking the `.blend1` backup file, but if you already saved more than once it won't help you much either.

Answer (score 2):

Blender saves one (by default) backup version of the file when you save it. You can look in it (it's named *whatever*.blend1) to see if it has the version you want.

Also, Blender also saves a backup file as you work, every 2 minutes by default. You can use File > Recover Auto Save... to restore this and see if it has the version you want.

If neither of these work, you are probably out of luck this time. There are a few things you can do to keep it from happening again, though:

- Increase the *Undo Levels* in Editing preferences, so you can go back farther. I use 256 myself, but you may want to try less if it makes you run out of memory.
- Increase the number of .blendX backup files Blender makes, in File preferences. I use 32, but this may be too many for you.

After changing any settings, **remember to press the Save User Settings button!** Otherwise, your changes will not be saved.